# Is it possible to annotate class constructor in Kotlin

Tags: annotations, kotlin

**Clarification**
This questions was asked before `kotlin` hit version 1.0. Language syntax in example is obsolete now, please follow official docs.

---

I'm playing with **kotlin** and **spring DI**.
I want to use constructor-based dependency injection, so I need to annotate the constructor.

I tried following approach:

```
Configuration
Import(javaClass<DataSourceConfig>())
public open class AppConfig(dataSource: DataSource) {
    private val dataSource: DataSource

    Autowired {
        this.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}

Configuration
public open class DataSourceConfig {

    Bean
    public open fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        // source omitted
    }
```

}

### But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to annotate constructor in kotlin?

P.S. I'm using Kotlin M10.1 and Spring 4.1.4

**UPDATE:**
Annotating constructor is possible in kotlin. **The problem was that it's not allowed to use constructor-based DI for @Configuration**

Comment: My only question is Why are you using M10? There's a version 1 beta 4 out right now that should work better. You don't have to actually answer this. I was just surprised see a milestone release being used still.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hrm, I think the syntax has changed radically since this question was posted. The current way (according to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)) is to add the keyword `constructor` between your class name and arguments and annotate *that*, i.e.

```
public class AppConfig @Configuration constructor(dataSource: DataSource) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write:

```
Configuration
public open class AppConfig [Import(javaClass<DataSourceConfig>())] (dataSource: DataSource) {
//...
}
```

Comment: the problem is not **Import** annotation, it works. The problem is that **spring** is trying to access default-constructor (which obviously fails) - which means it doesn't find any **annotated** non-default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for me:

```
Configuration
Import(javaClass<DataSourceConfig>())
public open class AppConfig {
  private val dataSource: DataSource

  Autowired constructor(dataSource: DataSource){
    this.dataSource = dataSource
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach is not working for me. First the compiler complains that "Primary constructor call is expected". Then if I add `this()` call to the constructor, it complains that "Val cannot be reassigned". Using kotlin  version 0.11.91.1. Tx