# How to implement base class that takes object and class as parameter for Glance Widgets?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, glance-appwidget

I am trying to create a base class `GenericAction` to handle Glance widget updates. It needs to take two parameters: an Object `GlanceStateDefinition` and Class `GlanceAppWidget()` as each widget will have a different state definition and broadcast receiver to be updated. This is called in
`updateAppWidgetState` and `updateStart` respectively.

I have followed the guidance provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413298/how-to-implement-a-zero-argument-constructor-base-class-that-dynamically-creates/74413581?noredirect=1#comment131369117_74413581) and got to the below code.

There are two problems I am facing:

1. Compilation error in lambda of `updateAppWidgetState()` I get `error - Unresolved reference: copy`. I believe this is because the compiler doesn't know how to infer the generic type `T`.
2. Runtime error on instantiation of `glanceWidget`. `Error in Glance App Widget java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.myproject.WidgetSymbolClass.<init> [class android.content.Context]`. I believe android can't find the constructor of my GlanceAppWidget `WidgetSymbolClass()` for some reason.

I would appreciate if anyone has any idea of how I can get rid of these errors and fix the below code in `GenericAction()`.

```kotlin
abstract class GenericAction<T>(val myObject: GlanceStateDefinition<T>, val myClass: Class<out WidgetSymbolClass>) : ActionCallback {

    override suspend fun onAction(context: Context, glanceId: GlanceId, parameters: ActionParameters) {
        val index = parameters.get(ActionParameters.Key<Int>("IndexParam")) ?: 0
        val portfolioId = parameters.get(ActionParameters.Key<String>("PortfolioId")) ?: "Portfolio 1"
        val showPortfolioMenu = parameters.get(ActionParameters.Key<Boolean>("showMenu")) ?: false

        updateAppWidgetState(context, myObject, glanceId) { state ->
            state.copy(
                /*error - Unresolved reference: copy*/
                /*error - Type mismatch. Required: T Found: Unit*/
                showPortfolioMenu = showPortfolioMenu,
            )
        }

        val glanceWidget = myClass.getConstructor(Context::class.java).newInstance(context) /*error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException WidgetSymbolClass.<init>*/
        glanceWidget.updateStart( glanceId = glanceId, portfolioId = portfolioId, index = index)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class WidgetSymbolShowMenu: GenericAction<WidgetSymbolState>(WidgetSymbolStateDefinition, WidgetSymbolClass::class.java)
```

```kotlin
class WidgetSymbolClass @JvmOverloads constructor() : WidgetAbstractClass()
```

```kotlin
abstract class WidgetAbstractClass (): GlanceAppWidget() {

    fun updateStart(
        glanceId: GlanceId?,
        appWidgetId: Int? = null,
        index: Int = 0,
        portfolioId: String = "Portfolio 1"
    ) {
       /*start updating widget*/
    }
}
```

```kotlin
/*myObect1 - T is WidgetSymbolState*/
object StateDefinitionSymbol: GlanceStateDefinition<WidgetSymbolState> {
    override suspend fun getDataStore(
        context: Context,
        fileKey: String,
    ): DataStore<WidgetSymbolState> = context.widgetSymbolFile

    override fun getLocation(context: Context, fileKey: String): File {
        return context.dataStoreFile(widgetSymbolJson)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
/*myObect2 - T is WidgetTableState*/
object StateDefinitionTable: GlanceStateDefinition<WidgetTableState> {
    override suspend fun getDataStore(
        context: Context,
        fileKey: String,
    ): DataStore<WidgetTableState> = context.widgetTableFile

    override fun getLocation(context: Context, fileKey: String): File {
        return context.dataStoreFile(widgetTableJson)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class WidgetSymbolState(
    val index: Int = 0,
    val portfolio: String = "Portfolio 1",
    val portfolioSize: Int = 0,
    val showPortfolioMenu: Boolean = false,
)
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class WidgetTableState(
    val portfolioId: String = "",
    val showPortfolioMenu: Boolean = false,
)
```

Comment: Well, now that you showed what `WidgetSymbolClass` looks like, it is obvious isn't it? There is, as a matter of fact, no constructor in `WidgetSymbolClass` that takes a `Context`. Why are you trying to pass the `context` to `myClass` in the first place? As for the compiler error, I'm assuming `WidgetSymbolState` is a data class? What other types are possible for `T`? Please *show* them.

Comment: ah yes that has fixed the `NoSuchMethodException`. yes `WidgetSymbolState` is a data class. I have added the data classes and two examples of Type T - `WidgetSymbolState` and `WidgetTableState`. The reason I used generic `T` is because I would like to switch `myObject` to be `StateDefinitionSymbol : GlanceStateDefinition<WidgetSymbolState>` or  `StateDefinitionTable : GlanceStateDefinition<WidgetTableState>` depending on what I feed `GenericAction`. The `myClass` param would also change based on which one i use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the compiler error, you need to assure the compiler that you can call `copy` on `T`. However, `WidgetSymbolState.copy` has a different signature from `WidgetTableState.copy`, despite both having a `showPortfolioMenu` parameter - they have different parameters because they are generated from different data classes. This means you cannot create a common interface between them and put `copy` there.

I would suggest that you add a `updateShowPortfolioMenu` method in both classes, and use that as the common interface.

```
interface ShowPortfolioMenuState<T: ShowPortfolioMenuState<T>> {
    fun updateShowPortfolioMenu(newValue: Boolean): T
}

@Serializable
data class WidgetSymbolState(
    val index: Int = 0,
    val portfolio: String = "Portfolio 1",
    val portfolioSize: Int = 0,
    val showPortfolioMenu: Boolean = false,
): ShowPortfolioMenuState<WidgetSymbolState> {
    override fun updateShowPortfolioMenu(newValue: Boolean) =
        copy(showPortfolioMenu = newValue)
}

@Serializable
data class WidgetTableState(
    val portfolioId: String = "",
    val showPortfolioMenu: Boolean = false,
): ShowPortfolioMenuState<WidgetTableState> {
    override fun updateShowPortfolioMenu(newValue: Boolean) =
        copy(showPortfolioMenu = newValue)
}
```

Then you can constraint `T` in `GenericAction` to `ShowPortfolioMenuState`:

```
abstract class GenericAction<T: ShowPortfolioMenuState<T>>(...)
```

And then call `state.updateShowPortfolioMenu(showPortfolioMenu)`, instead of `state.copy`.

As for the runtime error, `WidgetSymbolClass` does not have a constructor that takes a `Context`. I'm not sure why you are passing a `context` to it. Either don't pass a context to it:

```
myClass.getConstructor().newInstance()
```

Or add a `Context` parameter, if other classes that would passed to `myClass` *does* take a `Context`.

Also, you don't need the `@JvmOverloads`. There are no optional parameters anywhere.

Comment: I have raised another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438401/how-to-inject-parameters-into-android-worker-that-are-only-known-at-runtime) following on from this one. Basically it's how can I pass `myObject` and `myClass` to a `Worker`.