# How to inject parameters into Android Worker that are only known at runtime?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, glance-appwidget

## Goal

How can I pass `myObject` and `myClass` parameters to `GlanceWorker` below?

## Background

I am using `android-workmanager` to run background tasks. These tasks are initialized from a home screen widget which I have added with [Glance](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance). As recommended by Google [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/demystifying-jetpack-glance-for-app-widgets-8fbc7041955c) (see “How do I fetch data?”) I use the worker to update the Glance composable which is started from an `ActionCallback`.

To update my widget, the worker constructor needs to take two extra parameters `myObject` and `myClass` (in addition to `context` and `workerParameters`). All examples that I have read so far have mentioned the use of a `WorkerFactory` in order to achieve this. This extra parameter is always provided to the factory at start-up or injected via the dagger graph.

However, in my case, the type of these extra parameters is dependent on which widget initiated the `ActionCallback` (each widget has its own extension of `GlanceStateDefinition()` and `GlanceAppWidget()`). Therefore I can only provide the extra parameters to the worker at runtime (as far as I'm aware) and don't know how to have it pre-provided to the custom `WorkerFactory`. To make it more complicated, one of my extra parameters uses a generic `T`.

```kotlin
abstract class Action<T : ShowPortfolioMenuState<T>>(
    val myObject: GlanceStateDefinition<T>,
    val myClass: Class<out WidgetAbstractClass>,
) : ActionCallback {

    override suspend fun onAction(
        context: Context,
        glanceId: GlanceId,
        parameters: ActionParameters,
    ) {
        val glanceIdInt = GlanceAppWidgetManager(context).getAppWidgetId(glanceId)
        val showMenu = parameters[ActionParameters.Key("showMenu")] ?: false

        val glanceWork =
            OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(GlanceWorkerPortfolioChange::class.java)
                .setInputData(
                    workDataOf("GLANCE_ID" to glanceIdInt, "SHOW_MENU" to showMenu)
                ).build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .beginUniqueWork("Worker Name",
                ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                glanceWork
            ).enqueue()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@HiltWorker
class GlanceWorker<T: ShowMenuState<T>> @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    val myObject: GlanceStateDefinition<T>, /*<--- how do i add to constructor*/
    val myClass: Class<out WidgetAbstractClass>, /*<--- how do i add to constructor*/
    ): CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {
    
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val glanceIdInt = inputData.getInt("GLANCE_ID", -1)
        val glanceId = GlanceAppWidgetManager(context).getGlanceIdBy(glanceIdInt)
        val showMenu = inputData.getBoolean("SHOW_MENU", false)

        myClass.apply {
            updateAppWidgetState(context, myObject, glanceId) { state -> /*state is of type T*/
                state.updateShowMenu(showMenu)
            }
            update(context, glanceId)
        }
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your worker should be pulling this configuration information from a repository, rather than trying to push the values into the worker.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not sure what you mean. You mean a repository that holds objects and a bunch of inner classes? If so, how do I initialize the inner classes when I call them from the Worker? Also, I need to tell the Worker what objects/classes it needs to pull from the repository, So I would need to pass in some runtime information into the Worker anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Actions can't take parameters. Glance won't be able to instantiate the class and fail. Instead:

   1. Use the ActionParameters to pass the Class name as String and then use `Class.forName(..)` to get the type/instance.
   2. Use the GlanceAppWidget instance to get the state https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/GlanceAppWidget#(androidx.glance.appwidget.GlanceAppWidget).getAppWidgetState(android.content.Context,androidx.glance.GlanceId)
2. You can do the same for the worker by passing it as `workData`

Some workers examples:

https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/main/AppWidget/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/appwidget/glance/weather/WeatherWorker.kt

https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/main/AppWidget/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/appwidget/glance/image/ImageWorker.kt